# Prove $((A \cup D) \times (C \triangle B)) \setminus (A \times (B \cap C)) = ((A \setminus D) \cup D) \times (C \triangle B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

My Attempt:

$(x, y) \in ((A \cup D) \times (C △ B)) \setminus (A \times (B \cap C)) \iff ((x, y) \in (A \cup D) \times (C △ B)) \land ((x, y) \notin A \times (B \cap C))\iff((x \in (A \cup D)) \land (y \in (C △ B))) \land ((x \notin A) \lor (y \notin (B \cap C))) \iff ((x \in A) \lor (x \in D)) \land(y \in (C △ B)) \land ((x \notin A) \lor ((y \notin B) \land (y \notin C)))\iff((x \notin A) \land ((x \in A) \lor (x \in D)) \land (y ∈ (C △ B))) \lor ((y \notin B) \land (y \notin C) \land ((x \in A) \lor (x \in D)) \land (y \in (C △ B))) \iff E1 ∨ E2, $

$E1 = (x \notin A) \land ((x \in A) \lor (x \in D)) \land (y \in (C △ B));$

$E2 = (y \notin B) \land (y \notin C) \land ((x \in A) \lor (x \in D)) \land (y \in (C △ B)).$

$E1 \iff((x \notin A) \land (x \in A)) \lor ((x \notin A) \land (x \in D)) \land (y \in (C △ B))\iff(0 \lor ((x \in A) \land (x \in D))) \land (y \in (C △ B))\iff(x \in D \setminus A) \land (y \in (C △ B));$

For E2 I have 0 and in the end I don`t have correct answear.
Help me, please find my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$(A\setminus D)\cup D = A\cup D$ and $(C\triangle B) \cap (C\cap B) = \emptyset$, so equality is trivial.